# Inserting DATA to table A , after data is inserted into other table B using trigger in Oracle 9i

Tags: oracle, triggers

we have a table A which we have to uplaod daily then after inserting into A we have to move data from table A to Table B (in agregaated form),this we do manualy..Cant we have trigger which calls a procedure and populate Table B automaticaly when ever data comes in table A.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple example which does almost exactly what you want, http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/answer/Calling-a-stored-procedure-from-a-trigger